# Problem passing the correct value in ID to another page

Tags: php

I am using a form to edit comments and using the hidden input fields to pass the value,

the form is something like this.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="input" />
<input type="hidden" name="com_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="input" />
<input type="hidden" name="com_email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" class="input" />
<input type="hidden" name="com_phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" class="input" />
<input type="hidden" name="com_location" value="<?php echo $location;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="com_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<textarea name="comment" cols="" rows="" class="comment-msg"><?php echo $comment; ?>
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="com_comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>"/>
<input name="com_update_1" type="submit" class="btn-70" value="" />
```

and i am using the while loop to iterate the value in the form fields. my while loop code is

```
$query = "SELECT comments.*,
                news.title 
                FROM comments JOIN news ON comments.news_id = news.id
                ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from, " . COMM_POST_NUMBER;
      $result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $date = date("d-F-Y", $row['timestamp']);
      $name = stripslashes($row['name']);
      $email = stripslashes($row['email']);
      $phone = stripslashes($row['phone']);
      $location = stripslashes($row['location']);
      $comment = stripslashes($row['comment']);
      $news_id = $row['news_id'];
      $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
      $approve = $row['approve'];
```

The Iteration works well and it prints the value from the database perfectly and the hidden input field with value ID holds the correct value in this page i.e(comments.php). but when i want to pass the value to different page `<form action="action.php" method="post">`  my trouble starts it takes only the first id when i hit submit. i.e id with value 1 and it refuses to take any other values from id.

Here is the code from the view source code of the browser

```
<div class="comments-toggle">
 <input type="text" name="name" value="My Name is 16" class="input" />
 <input type="hidden" name="com_name" value="My Name is 16"/>
 <input type="text" name="email" value="check@email.com" class="input" />
 <input type="hidden" name="com_email" value="check@email.com"/>
 <input type="text" name="phone" value="919999999999" class="input" />
 <input type="hidden" name="com_phone" value="919999999999"/>
 <input type="text" name="location" value="Somewhere" class="input" />
 <input type="hidden" name="com_location" value="Somewhere"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="com_id" value="16"/>
 <textarea name="comment" cols="" rows=""class="comment-msg">                              
</textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="com_comment" value=""/>
  <input name="com_update" type="submit" class="btn-70" value="" />                        
   </div>
```

here is the code from action.php

```
 if( isset($_POST['com_update'])) {
        echo $id = $_POST['com_id'];
    if( isset($_POST['name'])) {
        echo $name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']))); 
        $query = "UPDATE comments SET name = '$name' WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error');
        }
```

how do i make it pass the correct id values to action.php?

Comment: So you create input fields for every comment? Do you also create a `<form>` element for every comment? If not, you have to do that. If you put everything in one form, PHP will always only take the first value if there are fields with the same name (except you specify them as array).

Comment: Why do you need to mirror the actual inputs with a hidden input each?

Comment: i have some 20 comments with different id's in the table, and using the while loop to populate and show it in the respective input fields (i.e for every database query it will output a form automatically). my form structure is such that of wordpress i am using quick edit to change the comments values.

Comment: @Extrakun the hidden input field is to check the changes and pop out appropriate message.

Comment: but you already have all these values in the database. What kind of message? Whole code seems weird to me

Comment: Not to mention disastrously insecure. You've got SQL injection, HTML injection, and totally inappropriate use of `stripslashes`, `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: i am using mysql_real_escape_string as well. what do you suggest and i dont understand why is it so insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to define your form fields as being ready for conversion to PHP arrays:

```
<input type="hidden" name="com_id[]" value="16"/>
```

Now, `$_POST['com_id']` should be an array of values.